# Function call interpreted as declaration

Tags: c++, declaration

The function call below generates compiler error:

```
void myfun() {}

myfun(); // error:
         // gcc -- error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ';' token
         // clang -- error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations

int main()
{
  // ...
}
```

Can somebody explain it? How is the function call confused with a declaration? Why does the error go away if the function call is moved inside `main()`?

Comment: You can't call a function there.

Comment: Function calls would need to go within main, or within another function (or member function)

Comment: _"This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting. "_

Comment: @AndyG No trolling, sorry for the silly question.

Comment: @AndyG To be fair, I could think about a failed attempt of a canonical with premature posting the question without the answer.

Comment: @user0042 Believe it or not I spent the last hour or so scratching my head on this. I just didn't know that a function returning `void` is not valid in global scope, and could not find the relevant rule anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot execute function calls outside of functions unless you use them for variable initialization. So you should write ...

```
void myfun() {}

int main()
{
  myfun();
}
```

or

```
int myfun() { return 1; }

int dummy = myfun(); 

int main()    {
}
```